# Getting Slice of one dimension in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multidimensional-array

I have a series of images with [x,y,z,r,g,b] stored per pixel per frame so the whole thing makes a 20*480*640*6 array. I want to slice off the r,b,g so I can display a regular image. I'm new to numpy and everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.
I think it should be something like:

```
rgb_frames = frames[:][:][:][3:]
```

or

```
rgb_frames = frames[:,:,:,3:] (gives too many indices error)
```

but neither of those are working.

Comment: What does `frames.shape` return?  `frames[:,:,:,3:]` should have worked if it had shape `(20, 480, 640, 6)`.

Comment: @DSM This is part of what I find a bit confusing... `frames.shape` gives (20,) but `frames[0].shape` gives (480, 640, 6). How does it decide where to get this dimension from?

Comment: Looks like your `frames` is not a `4d` array as you think, it is a `1d` array, with each element being `3d` array. Add a line of `frames=np.asanyarray(frames)` and thing should work after that.

Comment: @CT Zhu - How does it know the difference? It is being brought in from a matlab .m data file if that makes a difference using scipy.io.loadmat('datafile.m'), which imports it as a dict and then I get it out of the dict by the variable name it was called in the .m file.

Comment: @CTZhu Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything that I can see. The array is the same shape before and after.